# Installing Kodi and X server on FreeNAS

Tags: software-installation, freebsd, x-server, freenas, xbmc

I couldn't find how to install X server and Kodi on FreeNAS.
So without any opinion if it's good or not, what are the steps to do it?

Comment: Why FreeNAS? Does FreeNAS even support 3rd party packages?
I would first go with a FreeBSD installation then you can just do "pkg install xorg". No idea about FreeNAS if it ships the pkg tool. And frankly I do not care, because ppl who want to run a X server should use FreeBSD and not FreeNAS, which is FreeBSD specialized for Network Attached Storage (not for Xorg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a desktop environment:

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/x11-wm.html

update portsnap:

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html

then:

```
pkg install kodi
```

https://www.freshports.org/multimedia/kodi